# retrofit-2 - Getting 403 reponse code while uploading image and audio to aws server

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit2, multipart

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("http://ec2-18-216-193-78.us-east-
           2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000//api/v1/snapNShare")
    Call<SnapNShareResponse> sendUserReview(
            @Header("Authoriozation") String token,
            @Part("restaurantInfoId") String restaurantInfoId,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part dishPicture,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part audioReview,
            @Part("textReview") String textReview,
            @Part("rating") Integer rating);
```

And ApiClient is as follows :
Here, my project is integrated with Dagger library .

```
 @Singleton
    public class ApiClient {

        @Inject
        ApiClient() {
        }

        private static Retrofit retrofitBaseURL = null;
        private static Retrofit retrofitGOOGLEURL = null;

        public static Retrofit getClient(Context context, String base_url) {

            if (NetworkUtility.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor)
                        .readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .connectTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                if (null == retrofitBaseURL && base_url.equals(WebConstants.BASE_URL)) {
                    retrofitBaseURL = new Retrofit.Builder()


                   .baseUrl(base_url)
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            } else if (null == retrofitGOOGLEURL && base_url.equals(WebConstants.GOOGLE_BASE_URL)) {
                retrofitGOOGLEURL = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(base_url)
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return base_url.equals(WebConstants.BASE_URL) ? retrofitBaseURL : retrofitGOOGLEURL;

        } else {
            SnapXToast.showLongToast(context, "");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my retrofit request in which I want upload image and audio file to aws server. And the retrofit function is as follows :

```
public void sendReview(String restId, Uri image, Uri audio, String txtReview, Integer rating) {
        if (NetworkUtility.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
            ApiHelper apiHelper = ApiClient.getClient(mContext, BASE_URL).create(ApiHelper.class);

            String fileImagePath = getRealPathFromURIPath(image, mContext);
            String fileAudioPath = getRealPathFromURIPath(audio, mContext);

            File fileImg = new File(fileImagePath);
            File fileAud = new File(fileAudioPath);

            RequestBody mFileImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), fileImg);//here I tried with media type "image/*" 
            RequestBody mFileAudio = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), fileAud);//here I tried with media type "audio/*" 

            MultipartBody.Part imageUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("dishPicture", fileImg.getName(), mFileImage);
            MultipartBody.Part audioUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("audioReview", fileAud.getName(), mFileAudio);

            Call<SnapNShareResponse> snapXUserCall = apiHelper.sendUserReview(
                    utility.getAuthToken(mContext)
                    , restId, imageUpload, audioUpload, txtReview, rating);
            snapXUserCall.enqueue(new Callback<SnapNShareResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<SnapNShareResponse> call,
                                       Response<SnapNShareResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful() && null != response.body()) {
                        SnapNShareResponse nShareResponse = response.body();
                        mReviewPresenter.response(SnapXResult.SUCCESS, nShareResponse);
                        SnapXToast.showToast(mContext,"yasss");
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<SnapNShareResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    mReviewPresenter.response(SnapXResult.FAILURE, null);
                }
            });
        } else {
            mReviewPresenter.response(SnapXResult.NONETWORK, null);
        }
    }
```

//And the response getting is ,

403 Forbidden http://ec2-18-216-193-78.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/v1/snapNShare (16878ms)
    X-Powered-By: Express
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
04-29 22:20:29.685 9724-14733/com.snapxeats D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 36
    ETag: W/"24-9ze4gN/8B8Z0boWkFyxw9xuo9cA"
    Date: Sun, 29 Apr 2018 16:50:30 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
04-29 22:20:29.690 9724-14733/com.snapxeats D/OkHttp: {"message":"User not authenticated"}

Do I need to add "Header" part in my request seperately ?

Also in logcat for image and audio I am getting such logs:

J�p?p�AN��ynnd���ʖ����V���g�8C#�凨4�h�7qL-߾~����
    h41 BF�4�&���T�\y�q�A�I��Rj�@НJ�����)2���RAo=ϐ.-�����hH�$nGx�{��P�ռqM����<��5���l��sI�q��   �
    --cd1c8557-c8c3-498f-80ac-3434f9d19840
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audioReview"; filename="AUD_20180429_213143.mp3"
    Content-Type: */*
    Content-Length: 4603

//same for image

For "Unexpected EOF" I added "mPlayer.release();" which eliminated the error. 
Can anybody help me out in which part I am missing ? I checked with file names for images and audio ; they are successfully saved to local. And using :
    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

Please let me now if I need to add any more information regarding my query. 
Thanks !!

Comment: you can use aws s3 sdk , its very easy ! have a look https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html

Comment: share **ApiClient.java**

Comment: @NavneetKrishna Added Apiclient class. Please have a look.